# Azure Devops Maven depency for REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Used the REST API and got the details of the build and able to get the JSON responce

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#build

Is there a Maven dependency which is available so as to add dependency and then parse the returned JSON .

Appericate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Maven dependency for azure devops.
 You need to send http request to call Azure devops api in java and parse the returned response use maven dependencies that handles json.

You can refer to the java example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044652/how-to-connect-vsts-azure-devops-using-rest-api-in-java-i-am-not-getting-any-do) to call azure devops api.

For maven dependencies that handle json, there are GSON, Jackson and other dependencies that are available.

You can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) to find more json dependencies and examples.